# How to apply jQuery effects on Bootstrap pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap pagination in my design:

```
<ul class="pagination news-pages">
    <li id="prev" ><a href="javascript:get_pages('0')">&laquo;</a></li>
    <li id="page-1" class="active"><a href="javascript:do_sth('1')">1</a></li>
    <li id="page-2"><a href="javascript:do_sth('2')">2</a></li>
    <li id="next"><a href="javascript:get_pages('3')">&raquo;</a></li>
</ul>
```

and I'm trying to apply the jQuery `.hide()` method with sliding effect on it.
Just before I change it's content.

```
function get_pages(start_page)
{
    if(start_page=='0') return false;
    $(".news-pages").hide("slide", {direction:"left"}, "slow");

    /*other ajax stuffs, change displayed page number*/

    return fales;
}
```

I've tried this code several times but nothing happened.
Then, I removed all the arguments passed into `.hide()`.

```
$(".news-pages").hide();
```

It works! The component disappeared without any effect.
What's wrong with my code?

BTW, I've also tried jQuery effect `.toggle()` and it is even not working without arguments.
Another function I've tried is `.fadeOut()`, it works perfectly but it's not the effect I want.

Comment: you have to apply float left to all your pagination divs... and container has to have overflow hidden... and after that you can do it with the margin left -/+....

Answer (score 1):

**Try Something Like this :**

```
function get_pages(start_page)
{
    if(start_page=='0') return false;
      $(".news-pages").hide("slow",function(){
        alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
      });
return false;
    }
```

Hope it helps...